# Core Data: Managed Class not finding its property

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject

Hia,

I got a somewhat odd problem.

Im using two managed Classes that relate 1 to 1 to each other.
One is called CharInfo and the other is named ItemInfo.

```
CharInfo.h
@property (nonatomic, retain) ItemInfo * slotEar;
CharInfo.m
@dynamic slotEar;
```

When I try to set the property like this:

```
charInfo.slotEar = curentChar.slotEar;
```

does the program crash:

```
-[CharInfo setSlotEar:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68d4d60
```

Id course does my object charInfo have a property that can hold the reference.

```
curentChar.m
@property (nonatomic, retain) ItemInfo *slotEar;
curentChar.h
@synthesize slotEar;
```

The reference works, because the app can use the reference and use the ItemInfo to calculate things.

Technical it looks ok to me. Everything works, means I can create CharInfo, set all properties, even other relations like CharDetail, but not any of those that refer to ItemInfo.

Any idea what might be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a problem with versioning. The App dont use versioning, but the xtcdatamodel was actually xtcdatamodeld.

Answer (score 0):

Check your managed object model in the Core Data designer and check that you really added the one-to-one relationship to `ItemInfo` called `slotEar`.